# java.io.StreamCorruptedException:Wrong format:56

Tags: java, android

During this time, I develop an android application, use Object[Input/Output]Stream to send/receive message.The following code is send method:

```
public void sendMsg(Message msg) {
    try {
        if(connectedFalg) {
            outputStream.reset();
            outputStream.writeObject(msg);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

at the same time, there is a thread to receive message all the time, the code is following:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        Message msg = (Message) inputStream.readObject();
        BufferManager.INSTANCE.addReceiveQueue(msg);
    } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my project, I have three ball, one ball is target ball, others are controlled by mobile phone by accelerate sensor.At first i send the state of No.1 ball, and then send the No.2 ball or target ball, then it will have some exception.Like:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException:Wrong format:56
05-15 21:53:02.220: W/System.err(5923):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream(ObjectInputStream.java:676)
05-15 21:53:02.230: W/System.err(5923):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:789)
```

and some times it will have this problem:

```
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690): java.io.UTFDataFormatException: bad byte at 122
```

05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.nio.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode(ModifiedUtf8.java:60)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:179)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:173)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:169)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldDescriptors(ObjectInputStream.java:895)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:1719)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1631)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:658)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:762)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1981)
05-16 15:42:28.380: W/System.err(14690):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1938)

This is the project https://github.com/Aresxiao/DataStreamEngine/tree/dev

If two ball collide, then will call collisionCalculate() method,the method is following:

```
public boolean collisionCalculate(float ballaTempXY[],AbstractBall balla,AbstractBall ballb)
{       

    Value bvalue = KVStoreInMemory.INSTANCE.getVersionValue(new Key(ballb.getBallId())).getValue();
    float[] bloc = bvalue.getLoc();

    float BAx = ballaTempXY[0] - bloc[0];
    float BAy = ballaTempXY[1] - bloc[1];

    float mvBA = mould(new float[]{BAx, BAy});  

    if(mvBA > (balla.getRadius() + ballb.getRadius())){

        return false;
    }

    float[] bv = bvalue.getV();

    float vB = (float)Math.sqrt(bv[0] * bv[0] + bv[1] * bv[1]);

    float vbCollX = 0;
    float vbCollY = 0;
    //垂直方向的Xy分速度
    float vbVerticalX=0;
    float vbVerticalY=0;

    if(balla.getVMin() < vB)
    {
        float bAngle=angle
        (
            new float[]{bv[0],bv[1]},
            new float[]{BAx,BAy}
        );

        float vbColl=vB * (float)Math.cos(bAngle);

        vbCollX = (vbColl/mvBA) * BAx;
        vbCollY = (vbColl/mvBA) * BAy;

        vbVerticalX = bv[0] - vbCollX;
        vbVerticalY = bv[1] - vbCollY;
    }

    Value avalue = KVStoreInMemory.INSTANCE.getVersionValue(new Key(balla.getBallId())).getValue();

    float[] av = avalue.getV();

    float vA = (float)Math.sqrt(av[0] * av[0] + av[1] * av[1]);
    //平行方向的Xy分速度
    float vaCollX = 0;
    float vaCollY = 0;
    //垂直方向的Xy分速度
    float vaVerticalX = 0;
    float vaVerticalY = 0;

    if(balla.getVMin() < vA)
    {
        float aAngle=angle
        (
            new float[]{av[0],av[1]},
            new float[]{BAx,BAy}
        );          

        float vaColl=vA*(float)Math.cos(aAngle);

        vaCollX=(vaColl/mvBA)*BAx;
        vaCollY=(vaColl/mvBA)*BAy;

        vaVerticalX = av[0]-vaCollX;
        vaVerticalY = av[1]-vaCollY;
    }

    av[0] = vaVerticalX + vbCollX;
    av[1] = vaVerticalY + vbCollY;
    avalue.setV(av[0], av[1]);

    RegisterControllerFactory.INSTANCE.getRegisterController().write(new Key(balla.getBallId()), avalue);
    System.out.println("write balla "+balla.getBallId());
    bv[0] = vbVerticalX + vaCollX;
    bv[1] = vbVerticalY + vaCollY;

    bvalue.setV(bv[0], bv[1]);
    RegisterControllerFactory.INSTANCE.getRegisterController().write(new Key(ballb.getBallId()), bvalue);
    System.out.println("write ballb "+ballb.getBallId());

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You've written something else to the stream, and not read it with the converse of the method you used to write it, so you're now out of sync,

Comment: Are you run both the client side and server side on Android or one on Android , one on PC with java server? the java implementation may varies between Android java and JDK, I suggest you use more strict protocol to communicate not just rely on readObject 's inner implementation

Comment: I run both the client side and server side on Android phone.

Comment: @jobcrazy 
     
If it isn't strict, why does it throw this exception?